# Ripple effect only working on first ListView item

Tags: android

I have implemented the ripple effect introduced in Lollipop in a `ListView`. But it is only working for the first item of `ListView`. I've followed the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443496/listview-selector-with-colored-background-and-ripple-effect) but I'm unable to set a ripple effect.

I have a `ripple_background.xml` in `drawable-v21` folder:

```
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/background_dark">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

The layout my `ListView` exists in is as following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listSettings"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/price_item_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the items populated inside `ListView` is as follows (`settings_item_row.xml`):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_background"
    android:padding="16dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewIcon"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why aren't you using the ListView selector for this?

Comment: Because it makes a permanent *pressed* state after an item has been pressed.

Comment: I did exactly like you but I haven't faced any issue.

Comment: Please refer this Answer [Ripple effect does not show up sometime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27456582/ripple-effect-does-not-show-up-sometimes/44332007#44332007)

Answer (score 7):

I faced same issue and found an easy solution to this problem. No need to set any background to any list item or `ListView`. Just set `android:listSelector` to your ripple drawable in `ListView`.

So `ListView` in my activity look like:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        ...
        android:listSelector="@drawable/ripple" />
```

and my ripple drawable is defined as :

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/rippleColour">
    <item android:drawable="@color/backgroundColour"/>
</ripple>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem and fixed it. Remove the ripple background drawable from your individual list item views, and then set a background on the ListView itself. As well, add the drawSelector to your list item and remove field from your ListView.

This fix only works for having a single color background for the ListView.

Your List Item View:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_background"
    android:padding="16dp" >
```

And Your ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listSettings"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@color/price_item_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="@color/__Your color here__
    />
```

Comment: I am stuck at the same point. Can you please give more details. I see that you said to remove ripple background from list item view but in your code i can see android:background is set to ripple drawable. And I didn't get what you mean by 'add the drawSelector' and which field i need to remove from list view?
If you put an example ripple drawable, list view and list item, that would be very helpfull

Comment: Thanx. I found a solution and added it as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add any background to the layout.
Just leave your layouts as it is. Now concentrate on the ListView 
in ListView your can add your own background and you can use ListSelector to apply ripple theme.

By using ListSelector in ListView ripple effect will work on every item in the list and you can give default background to the list items also (separately in list View).

```
<ListView android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  android:id="@+id/list"  
  android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" 
  android:background="#fff" 
  android:listSelector="@drawable/ripp" />
```

Comment: <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/ripp"
    />

Comment: Thanks for participating. Please use the ***edit*** link below your answer to add your code into it.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me and I changed the clickable value to true than it worked.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  ....
  android:background="@drawable/touchselector"
  android:clickable="true">
  ....
</LinearLayout>
```